# How to query sqlalchemy model to get all records created yesterday?

Tags: python, date, flask, sqlalchemy

i'm using flask with flask-sqlalchemy. I have following model:

```py
from datetime import date

class View(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime(25), default=date.today)
    video_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('video.id'), nullable=False)
```

How can i get all views which timestamp is date from yesterday?

I have tried

```py
    x = db.session.query(View).filter(View.timestamp == date.today()-timedelta(days=1)).all()
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there! Think about this:

1 == 1 ?  Yes , easy!

But you have:

View.timestamp == date.today()-timedelta(days=1)

Which is asking:

17th April 2021 13:00:10  == 17th April 2021?   No it's not equal (==) It's very close, but it's not equal.

You probably want to use *between* instead of equal. e.g.

Is `<timestamp>` between `<yesterday>` and `<today>`? Yes.

Now you know what to look for, I'm sure you'll find it :)